# Double integration of x*np.log(x) in Python using scipy.integrate.dblquad

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, integral, entropy

The code below uses double integration with `scipy.integrate.dblquad` to calculate the differential entropy, `c*np.log(c)`, of a copula density function `c`, which has one dependence parameter, `theta`, usually positive. Formula can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829062/archimedean-clayton-copula-entropy).

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate 

def copula_entropy(theta):
    c = lambda v, u: ((1+theta)*(u*v)**(-1-theta)) * (u**(-theta) 
        + v**(-theta) -1)**(-1/theta-2)
    return -integrate.dblquad(c*np.log(c), 0, 1, lambda u: 0, lambda u: 1)[0]
```

Calling the function with

```
copula_entropy(1)
```

returns the error

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type function which has no callable log method
```

How can the function be made to work?

Comment: Dunno if it matters, but `((1+theta)*(u*v)**(-1-theta)) * (u*(-theta) + v*(-theta) -1)**(-1/theta)` doesn't seem to match the formula for c(u, v).

Comment: Oh its missing the `-2` at the end, thanks

Comment: Well, it also has `u*(-theta)` and `v*(-theta)` instead of `u**(-theta)` and `v**(-theta)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument must be a callable, so just wrap it in a `lambda` itself:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate 

def copula_entropy(theta):
    c = lambda v, u: ((1+theta)*(u*v)**(-1-theta)) * (u**(-theta)+v**(-theta)-1)**(-1/theta-2)
    return -integrate.dblquad(lambda u,v: c(v,u)*np.log(c(v,u)), 0, 1, lambda u: 0, lambda u: 1)[0]
```

(Please note that I also changed the expression for `c` according to the formula you gave).

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize I could pass in input arguments to lambda functions. wonder why it didn't work when `c` was made a defined function, which I also tried

Comment: any idea if the same lambda-wrap-lambda approach can be used for extending the integral to more than two variables (`u1,u2,u3,u4,...`) using `dblquad`?

Comment: it should work exactly the same way as here, just use `nquad` for n dimensions

Comment: but can lambda functions do that for an arbitrary number of n dimensions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65688402/multivariate-lambda-function-in-python-that-scales-with-number-of-input-variable

Comment: yes, like so `f = lambda *u: np.sum(np.array([*u]))`, but you can also use just a regular function

Comment: how should the `ranges` argument for `nquad` be altered? e.g. for 3 variables, there would now be 6 inputs for range?

Comment: see the documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html

Comment: Is the logarithmic part, `np.log(c)`, the reason why the lambda function is sent  to `integrate.dblquad`? `-integrate.dblquad(lambda u,v:...` Previously when I didn't know this could be done, I was noticing some sort of error regarding `loopfunc` which would go away when I removed the log term and only integrated `c`