# Multiple integral using scipy.integrate.nquad - errors on lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, scipy, syntax-error, integral

I attempt the following multiple integral in the code below for a higher-than-[bivariate version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65661541/double-integration-of-xnp-logx-in-python-using-scipy-integrate-dblquad) (`n=2`) of a copula density function, `c(u1,u2)`. In other words, `n>2` dimensions.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

def H(theta):
    c = lambda *us: ((1+theta)*np.prod(*us)**(-1-theta)) * (np.sum(*us **(-theta))-1)**(-1/theta-2)
    return -integrate.nquad(
        func   = lambda *us : c(*us)*np.log(c(*us)), 
        ranges = (0,1)**n, 
        args   = (theta,) 
        )[0] 

theta, n = 1, 3
print(H(theta))
```

where `*us` represents the arbitrary number of `u`'s I can pass in. The second input argument to `integrate.nquad`, which is `ranges=(0,1)**n`, is the [0,1] support of the integral due to `n` dimensions of `u`'s, which I try to explain in the derivation above. However, this part of the code gives the following error.

- `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'`

If I change this input to `ranges=(0,1)` by removing the exponent `n` as suggested by the error, then I get a different error:

- `low, high = fn_range(*args)`

  `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object`

How am I really supposed to declare the `[(0,1)**n]` support for a multiple integral in `integrate.nquad`? The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html) does not give a matching example.

Comment: You are missing a  `)` matching the first `(` at  `c = lambda *us: np.prod( ((1+theta)*np.prod(us)**(-1-theta)) * (np.sum(u**(-theta))-1)**(-1/theta-2)`. It should instead be `c = lambda *us: np.prod(((1+theta)*np.prod(us)**(-1-theta)) * (np.sum(u**(-theta))-1)**(-1/theta-2))`. Your identation is also broken

Comment: thanks. sorry for the indentation, the error was also there with my fixed code that hadn't been reflected in the post. anyway, with the missing bracket added, i now get the following : `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'`. i would like to resolve any further errors so that the script actually works

Comment: What is `(0,1)**n` supposed to be doing?  Have you tested that expression in an interactive Python session?

Comment: it's the support of the integral based on `u` being probability-integral transformed marginal distributions (which take on a range of [0,1]). It's entered where the `ranges` input argument is for `integrate.nquad`. I think that's how to write an integral support of [0,1] https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html

Comment: The error is quite descriptive. `(0, 1)` is a tuple which cannot be raised to an `int`. What are you actually trying to do at `(0,1)**n`?

Comment: that's how it's written in math formulas under the integral sign (unfortunately the image above assumes knowledge that marginals u have a support of `(0,1)**n`). `n` in the math context simply denotes n-dimensionality in that there are `n` u's, each `u` has a support of [0,1].

Comment: At most points, you can extract a subexpression into a temporary variable, which would tell you when a subexpression is invalid. That should allow you to extract a [mcve].

Comment: a reproducible example of the bivariate case, at least, that actually works was given in the first link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65661541/double-integration-of-xnp-logx-in-python-using-scipy-integrate-dblquad

Comment: based on the comments regarding the support, I realized that by cutting corners, the necessary background required for answering the question made it not even up to my own standards. please see now the updated image in the edit, where I give a more thorough exposition of the multiple integral and its support. thanks for your help

Comment: I've figured out how to add the support properly. It must be an iterable: `ranges = [(0,1) for i in range(n)]`

Answer (score 0):

Posting some comments as an answer since the comments section is getting overloaded.

(1) I think by `(0, 1)**2` you mean to say the product (0, 1) x (0, 1), i.e., the unit square. I don't think Python is going to understand that. If you need to tell nquad that the domain of integration is the unit square, I think you need to say that some other way.

(2) Please post the formula for the function you are actually working with, namely c(u). Bear in mind that when you omit details or defer them to links, it only makes it harder for others to understand and therefore less likely that you can get effective help.

(3) The domain of integration for entropy calculation is the so-called support of the probability function, that is, the set on which the probability is greater than zero. What is the support of c(u)? That defines the domain of integration. It is customary in textbooks or other expositions to say the domain is R or (-inf, +inf) or otherwise leave it ambiguous, but for an actual calculation you need to cut it down to the support.

I'm sorry I can't be more helpful, it's an interesting question.

Comment: I realize that by cutting corners the necessary background required for answering the question made it not even up to my own standards. please see now the updated image in the edit, where I give a more thorough exposition of the multiple integral and its support

Comment: I've figured out how to add the support properly. It must be an iterable: `ranges = [(0,1) for i in range(n)]`

Comment: Great, glad to hear you got it figured out. I will remember that in case I bump into it again.